# Objects in XML Layout is overlapping on keyboard showing

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

How do I ensure the the multiline edittext that starts with "+++++++++++++++++" is right below when the keyboard is showing.

Right now it shows up like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/pw95.png/

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bginset2" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTripName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trip Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#2B00E4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTripName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#569741"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="30" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etShowLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:lines="20"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnClear" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:background="@drawable/otherbuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear Trip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:background="@drawable/otherbuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Trip"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I ensure, the any open space between the Trip Name and the two buttons below is taken up by the EditText regardless if the keyboard is out or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set elements to be below one another so that when the keyboard comes up, they stay in their relative position.

for example to keep the edittext below the trip name textview you would do this

```
android:layout_below="@+id/tvTripName"
```